# Convergence in probability of normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I need some help with the following. I am given that $X_n\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ i.e. $X_n$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1/n$. I need to show that $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$. I started by doing

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\lvert X_n-0 \rvert\ge\epsilon\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(X_n\ge\epsilon\right)$$

and I don't know where to go from here. I though that I could use the cdf of the normal but this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Perhaps better, for a distribution symmetric about zero, to double the right hand side to say $\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\lvert X_n-0 \rvert\ge\epsilon\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}2 P\left(X_n\ge\epsilon\right)$

Answer (score 3):

By [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), for each $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\Pr\{|X_n|\ge\varepsilon\}\le\frac{\operatorname EX_n^2}{\varepsilon^2}=\frac1{\varepsilon^2n}\to0\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
Hence, $X_n\to0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Is that not Chebyshev's inequality? Also, $E(X_n^2)\neq1/n$.

Comment: Yes, you may call it Chebyshev's inequality (you can use Markov's inequality to prove Chebyshev's inequality). We have that $1/n=\operatorname {Var}X_n=\operatorname EX_n^2-(\operatorname EX_n)^2=\operatorname EX_n^2-0=\operatorname EX_n^2$. Hence, $\operatorname EX_n^2=1/n$.